# Auto generated codes showing as expired , before set expiry date

Tags: coupon, discount, coupon-codes

We have auto generated codes that last 3 days they are very simple coupon rules i.e 10% discount off all orders or free postage.

Once the code is generated if a customer tries to use them it will sometimes say that the code has already expired. I have checked and the code is still valid. This doesn't happen with all of the vouchers that are generated but I cannot see a pattern.

Any help?

Comment: You have to give us more information than this if you hope us to debug the issue for you! Refer to this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have Added more information